# Trying to create a generic repository that uses IQueryable for MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm currently implementing a generic MongoDB repository implementation. The current interface I have is:

```
public interface IBaseRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    void Create(TEntity obj);
    void Update(TEntity obj);
    void Delete(string id);
    Task<TEntity> Get(string id);
    Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> Get();
}
```

I've implemented these and it's good enough for basic things, but I need to be able to use LINQ, I'm not sure what the best way to do this while still keeping the repository generic?

Answer (score 1):

How about doing something like this

```
public interface IBaseRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    void Create(TEntity obj);
    void Update(TEntity obj);
    void Delete(string id);
    Task<TEntity> Get(string id);
    Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> Get();
    Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> GetList(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
}
```

And then the implementation would be something like (I'll use customer as an example)

```
public class SomeRepository : IBaseRepository<Customer>
{
    // rest of the implementation

    public virtual DbSet<Customer> Table => Context.Set<Customer>();

    Task<IEnumerable<Customer>> GetList(Expression<Func<Customer, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return Table.Where(predicate).ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

Note: I haven't worked with MongoDB but this should work with EF in general

Answer (score 0):

You can call the `AsQueryable` extension method directly on any Mongo collection.

> Hooking into the LINQ provider requires getting access to an `IQueryable` instance. The driver provides an `AsQueryable` extension method on `IMongoCollection`.
>
> ```cs
> var collection = db.GetCollection<Person>("people");
> var queryable = collection.AsQueryable();
> ```

Reference: https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.10/reference/driver/crud/linq/#queryable

The `AsQueryable` extension above actually returns an `IQueryable` instance that implements `IMongoQueryable` and has all the same `async` extensions that other ORMs (Entity Framework, NHibernate, etc.) have, so you can use LINQ all you want.